# Pagination with Eager Loading In Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-5.4, eager-loading

I have items table and bootstrap_themes table.

And relation between them is -------

**Item** hasOne **BootstrapTheme**

Now I am trying to filter bootstrapthemes according to the filter that item has.

```
$themes = BootstrapTheme::with(['item' =>function($q) use($request){
            if($request->has('is_saleable')){
                $q->where('is_saleable','=',$request->is_saleable);
            }
            if($request->has('is_disable')){
                $q->where('is_disable','=',$request->is_disable);
            }
        }])->paginate(30);
```

Suppose that I filter by is_disable attribute then the result set is as below:

> {"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"item_id":1,"created_at":"2017-08-17 11:24:14","updated_at":"2017-08-17 11:24:14","item":null}],"from":1,"last_page":1,"next_page_url":null,"path":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/all-themes","per_page":30,"prev_page_url":null,"to":1,"total":1}

My question is that is it possible to count BootstrapTheme as 0 in pagination when item is null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you want count,  you can use ->count();

Comment: I am still getting that bootstraptheme whose item is null. and in pagination it is counting the data as one row. In foreach loop i am checking                  @if($theme->item) @endif to show that bootstrapTheme but the pagination's function $themes->total() is showing 1. How can i check this??

Comment: You can use whereNull()

Answer (score 0):

You can use whereNull() Method to check for NULL  [advanced where clauses.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses)

```
$query = Model::where('field1', '=',  1)
->whereNull('field2')
->paginate(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution by using  [whereExists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) .
Now the bootstrapthemes will not be counted when there is no item.

```
$themes = BootstrapTheme::with(['item'])->whereExists(function($q) use ($request){
            $q->select(DB::raw(1))->from('items')->whereRaw('bootstrap_themes.item_id = items.id');
            if($request->has('is_saleable')){
                $q->where('items.is_saleable','=',$request->is_saleable);
            }
            if($request->has('is_disable')){
                $q->where('items.is_disable','=',$request->is_disable);
            }
        })->paginate(30);
```